# SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(...) vs getWritableDatabase

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I bundled a database with my app in the assets folder.
At the first activity, I copy the database to the correct location perfectly (no problem here).

my question; is it better to use
openDatabase (String path, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int flags)
or to use getWritableDatabase method of the SQLiteOpenHelper class?

which is more efficient?
I'm accustomed to using the getWritableDatabase method, which requires passing of Context, but I just feel I can do without it since I don't need the onUpgrade or onCreate function of the SQliteOpenHelper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getWritableDatabase` is just `SQLiteOpenHelper`'s way of opening databases.

If you do not need `SQLiteOpenHelper`, the you do not need to call `getWritableDatabase` either.

Comment: if I go with SQliteDatabase.openDatabase()
how do I optimise it during the Activity life-cylce?
for example, during onPause to release resources.
is it safe to use db.close() 
(where db is my SQLiteDatabase object)
thanks

Comment: That's a different question. And optimize for what? Speed? Memory? Maintainability?

Comment: I thought it was a good practice to always close any open databases during onPause() to free memory and the SQLiteOpenHelper close() method was perfect for that, and open() during onResume().
But with SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(), I can't find a suitable method to free memory or disconnect the database when leaving an Activity.

Comment: [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) is derived from [SQLiteClosable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteClosable.html), which has the [close method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteClosable.html#close%28%29).

Comment: thanks @CL, I've chosen the openDatabase() approach, and it's working as expected.